# Raphael newbie: what are cx, rx, ox in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

In Raphael.js [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) of official website, there are many parameters used, like `cx`, `ox`, `rx`, but what are the definitions for these parameters, can someone explain to me what are they represented for?

Where can I find the definitions for these parameters?

Comment: It looks like the `c` stands for `center`, `o` for `original` and `r` for `radius`.

Comment: @pimvdb, I am also thinking in this way, but the official documentation makes me confused..

Comment: +1; Yeah, I found it confusing too.

Answer (score 3):

They are listed right there in the documentaiton you linked:

- `rx` - Horisontal radius
- `cx` - X coordinate of the origin of rotation

`ox` is just a variable they use to store data.

Answer (score 0):

- CX - the x-axis coordinate of the center of the circle, or ellipse
- CY -the y-axis coordinate of the center of the circle, or ellipse
- RX - horisontal radius of the ellipse
- RY - vertical radius of the ellipse

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Raphael Documentation -  Element.attr](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr). The parameter descriptions you are looking for are explained there.

So `cx` denotes the center `x` coordinate while `rx` defines the horizontal (x-axis) radius of an ellipse or circle. Same applies for vertical direction with y.